# Writing data to a json file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to make a json.log which will get every http request with the time\url\method.
I succeed doing that and print it in console but I need it like this in a json file

```
{
  time: '31.10.2022:20:2',
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/form/contactAdmin'
},
{
  time: '31.10.2022:20:2',
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/form/contactAdmin'
}
,{
  time: '31.10.2022:20:2',
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/form/contactAdmin'
}
```

Thats how I tried to make it :

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const logObj = {
    time: `${
      date.toLocaleDateString() +
      ':' +
      date.getHours() +
      ':' +
      date.getMinutes()
    }`,
    method: req.method,
    url: req.url,
  };
  fs.appendFile(
    'log.json',
    JSON.stringify({ logObj }, null, '\t'),
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
      }
    }
  );

  next();
});
```

but the results are horrible :)
[image]

I would like to get some hints, I feel very close to the goal! thanks

Comment: It would be much easier to store each log message as an independent string each on a separate line in the log file (JSON should be formatted as a single line) and not to try to interpret the file content to as the whole single JSON object.

Comment: Ooopf. Don't do that. You can't tell where one JSON text ends and the next begins.  If you've going to use JSON then use *JSON Lines*. Seriously consider using a database instead.

Comment: appendFile is not efficient for this purpose. You should consider to opena a stream instead and to pipe your logs through it. Anyway, handling streams throughput could be difficoult and you should handle application crashes to avoid data corruption. You should consider using well tested libraries for logging like [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan), [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) or a combination of both.

Answer (score -1):

```js
fs.appendFile(
    'log.json',
    JSON.stringify({ time: `${
      date.toLocaleDateString() +
      ':' +
      date.getHours() +
      ':' +
      date.getMinutes()
    }`,  method: req.method, url: req.url, }, null, '\t'),
```

logObj is an object itself. Closing it within an object when appending in to your JSON file makes it an object within an object. So instead of creating a new object (logObj), instead append the data manually.